# Solution to get data from memory of a process

Tags: process, memory

If I'm using Firefox and filling out a big form (with lots of text to write), and for some reason I accidentally press <kbd>F5</kbd> and all my text in the forms is lost, I can use e.g. [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) on Windows to retrieve the text, because they're still in memory. How can I do the same under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse through the virtual `/proc/kcore` file (the image of the RAM) and look for a string you typed. So for example (all as root)

```
strings /proc/kcore | grep unbelievable
```

will look for a string `unbelievable`

```
hd /proc/kcore | less
```

will give you a hex formatted output of all the RAM.

As a sidenote, I would recommend using the [Lazarus FF/Chromium extension](http://lazarus.interclue.com/home), which can save your bacon/forms and prevent these problems.